# Confusion with vector addition

Tags: vector-analysis

So while reading a solid-state physics book, I encountered the following (drift-diffusion equation):

[image]

I know the divergence of a vector field produces a scalar field, and so the second equation is easy to understand. However, in the first equation the author is adding a vector to a scalar (no?). How does this come about? Am I missing something?

The definitions of the currents in the equation are as shown:

[image]

Comment: I suspect this is better suited for the [physics section](http://physics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: $\hat{j}^S$ is apparently a tensor, not a vector.

Comment: @RobertIsrael That is correct! Thanks.